# Test unit for a scheduler

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

I have to develop a scheduler to process old registers of some object..

LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90

How can I create a test unit for such a scheduler?
Is it possible to modify the LastModifiedDate  field to an older one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid having test-specific code segments, which is generally a bad idea because this means behaviour is different in tests compared with production, you can use `Test.loadData` or `JSON.deserialize` to populate test data that includes specific values for system fields.

You'll find this documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332070&type=1&mode=1).

In this specific case you do have an issue that you want to consider the LastModifiedDate. In such a scenario you may find that you have no option but to override some of the behaviour of the production code. I strive to avoid inclusion of Test.isRunningTest() in production code and instead ensure to use non-static methods so these can be mocked out in tests.

In this case I'd make sure the query is in a separate non-static and virtual method. In most tests I would use a specialization of the class, local to the test class, that overrides this query method to return without checking the LastModifiedDate value.

That doesn't mean that you never test the actual production code for this query; you can have one test that uses the normal class, and you can confirm that it selects no data to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create data normally and modify your query like this:

```
Test.isRunningTest() ? [SELECT Id FROM Account] : [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90];
```